# MSSQL 2016 Server: All databases marked Recovery Pending state

Tags: sql-server-2016

Tonight I had run into this issue where all my databases on our production server were in a Recovery Pending state after doing a Windows (server 2016) Update, an update to my Redgate SQL Backup software and restarting the server.  Looking at the logs I found that all of the databases were not accessible with an "Access denied" error.  So I figured it was something to do with the user under which the MSSQLSERVER service was running.  So I explicitly set permissions to the data and log folders for that user and restarted SQL Server service and all is fine again.

HOWEVER, this server has been running for a very long time - and I have not seen this kind of issue where suddenly the user doesn't have access to the data and log folders.  SOMETHING had to have removed permissions on those folders.  In addition, now when I look at the security tab of those folders, I see that the user I'm using to run the MSSQLSERVER is explicitly defined.  But on our staging server, which has the exact same configuration, I DO NOT see the user explicitly defined there, yet the server is running along just fine.

SO - To my question.  What the heck happened?  Any ideas?  Should I be worried that the user account running my MSSQLSERVER service is now explicitly defined in the Security tab of my data and log folders?

Comment: Not sure what exactly happened, it can be a number of things, however I have run into a similar issue last night right after a Windows update, on two separate computers on Windows 10 running a local instance of SQL Server Express 2016. After the update on both computers SQL Server began chewing around 30% CPU for hours on end, and during the whole time all of the opened databases at the time were marked as Recovery Pending. Being desktop machines I just restarted the instances and all the database thankfully came back just fine, and no recovery actually took place from the logs. Too weird.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows event log in the security and system sections? The workaround unblocked you for now but not knowing what happened means it might happen again plus manual ACLs are generally not a good idea. Setup and configuration manager makes sure all necessary ACLs everywhere are set correctly for the service account. Manually ACLing objects means you won't know what you might be missing and what else might break later.

Answer (score 1):

Use ALTER DATABASE ... REBUILD LOG ON. First set to Emergency, then rebuild the log, then set online and multi-user. You will get a warning that the database may not be transactionally consistent (and it is true).

```
Alter Database TestDB Set Emergency;
Go

Alter Database TestDB Rebuild Log On 
    (Name = N'TestDB_log',
    FileName = N'L:\Path\To\LogFile\TestDB_log.ldf')
Go

Alter Database TestDB Set Online, Multi_user;
Go
```